# Could not load type 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JwtSecurityToken'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, types, jwt

I have two libraries. One consumes the other and the consuming library is is itself used by a Web app. The Web app returns the error below whereas the code instantiating the type ( doping JWT signature validation ) is successfully executed in unit tests by both libraries. libraries, app are target framework .NET 4.5.2 I validated that the Web app's .csproj file has a valid reference

```
<Reference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, Version=5.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">      <HintPath>..\packages\System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.5.1.4\lib\net451\System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.dll</HintPath>
 </Reference>
```

I do not find the assembly in the GAC to remove

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0>gacutil /u System.IdentityMo
del.Tokens.Jwt
Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.17929
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

No assemblies found matching: System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt
Number of assemblies uninstalled = 0
Number of failures = 0
```

I have tried clean, rebuild, reboot, delete /bin and /lib and rebuilt and am at a loss. Personally, this may not be System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt per se, but guidance I need on troubleshooting such as type loading errors. I have resintalled the .Tokens package specifically and indeed all packages:

```
nuget install packages.config
```

I still get the error, not on build, but only on execution:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not load type 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JwtSecurityToken' from assembly 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, Version=5.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JwtSecurityToken' from assembly 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, Version=5.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

Source Error: 


Line 12:     protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
Line 13:     {
Line 14:       GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
Line 15:     }
Line 16: 

Source File: C:\Dev\Git\Connect-Applications\ControllerlessApp\src\Connect.Rest.MainApp\Global.asax.cs    Line: 14 

Stack Trace: 


[TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JwtSecurityToken' from assembly 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, Version=5.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, ObjectHandleOnStack retTypes) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes() +31
   Plex.Web.UI.ServiceResolverDefaults..ctor() +842

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +138
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +105
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +12
   Plex.Activation.AssemblyDefaultRegistrationConvention.Process(Type type, Registry registry) +118
   StructureMap.StringExtensions.Each(IEnumerable`1 enumerable, Action`1 action) in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\Extensions.cs:10
   StructureMap.StringExtensions.Each(IEnumerable`1 enumerable, Action`1 action) in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\Extensions.cs:10
   StructureMap.Graph.AssemblyScanner.ScanForAll(PluginGraph pluginGraph) in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\Graph\AssemblyScanner.cs:248
   StructureMap.Graph.PluginGraph.Seal() in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\Graph\PluginGraph.cs:121
   StructureMap.PluginGraphBuilder.Build() in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\PluginGraphBuilder.cs:72
   StructureMap.Container..ctor(Action`1 action) in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\Container.cs:25
   Plex.Activation.ServiceResolverBuilder.Initialize(ApplicationContext context) +288
   Connect.Rest.Framework.Hosting2.Infrastructure.AppDomainSharedServices.get_ServiceResolver() +1373
   Connect.Rest.Framework.Hosting2.WebApiConfig.Register(HttpConfiguration config) +80
   System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configure(Action`1 configurationCallback) +63
   Connect.Rest.MainApp.WebApiApplication.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Dev\Git\Connect-Applications\ControllerlessApp\src\Connect.Rest.MainApp\Global.asax.cs:14

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +544
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +186
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +402
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +343

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +579
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +112
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +716
```

Comment: Have you published to the bin folder the jwt libraries?

Comment: Thank you @Gusman  What I have done is taking all the DLLs from the base library that instantiates this type and does all necessary with them and copied them to the app's bin. This resulted in no change in behavior.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, what's odd is that it works in the unit test project but not when run in the web api, both projects using the same version of `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt`.  In my case I can't just downgrade to v4 because I have other dependencies that require v5, this is very irritating.

Answer (score 15):

I've resolved this issue by downgrading the package System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt to 4.0

And there is an issue on GitHub
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/issues/76